# Python: Regex to match multiline strings in C code

Tags: python, regex, string, multiline

I'm attempting to match multiline strings in C code via the `re` module.

I'd like to match strings of the form:

```
char * theString = "Some string \
                   I want to match.";
```

I tried the following regex, which does not work:

```
regex = re.compile(r"\".*\"$", re.MULTILINE)
```

I thought that it would match the first ", then continue searching the next line until it found a closing ", but this is not the case.  Is this because $ requires that there be a " at the end of the line to match?  Is there some way to do this using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot all flag.

However, this is the way to parse C strings.  `(?s)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`

if it doesn't support `(?s)` inline modifier, set the modifier in the flags parameter.

`re.compile(r'"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"', re.DOTALL)`

```
 (?s)
 "
 [^"\\]*                       # Double quoted text
 (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
 "
```

Ideally, you should add (raw regex) `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*` at the beginning,
to make sure the opening double quote is not escaped.

Comment: @ sln Using that expression in re.compile((?s)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*") produces a syntax error.  Have I used it incorrectly?  I'm new to python regex.

Comment: @VictorBrunell - You could use the _raw_ syntax, or just a normal double quoted string `"(?s)\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\""` Is it a language parse syntax error I presume? If its a regex syntax error, it might not like the modifier `(?s)` in which case take it out and use the _DOTALL_ flag from the options.

Comment: @ sln `re.compile("(?s)\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"")` returns no match as well unfortunately.

Comment: `re.compile(r'"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"',  re.DOTALL)`

Comment: @ sln When running that against the lines in my original post via `print myregex.findall(line)` it still returns `[]`, where `myregex = re.compile(r'"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"', re.DOTALL)`

Comment: I would double check your _line_ and usage of the function findall(). I use Perl and don't know Python. The regex is not the problem though, that I do know.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help.  I'll poke around some more and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @ sln This solution works.  The problem was that I was reading line by line from a file and using findall() on each line.  I needed to concatenate all the lines into one line and then use findall().